# catching a parts of a paragraph beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have used the findAll function on my soup object to find the data I want. All I need is to retrieve exactly what I want  **a href** link.
Here what I have:

```
Soup[0].a
#output:
<a href="School">
<div class="name">XXX</div>6 Lemaitre Avenue 65000</a>
```

I am able to get the reference (**School**) using the **attribs** of the link and the name of the school navigating to the div but I can't seem to get the  last part of the link which is the address of the school (this part right here: -> **6 Lemaitre Avenue 65000**)

Comment: you'll want to use `soup.a.text`, as that part is the text content of the tags/attributes. or in your case, `Soup[0].a.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use Next_element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = '''
<a href="School">
<div class="name">XXX</div>6 Lemaitre Avenue 65000</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile("School"))
for item in items:
    item=item.find('div').next_element.next_element
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
6 Lemaitre Avenue 65000
```

Comment: Brilliant, but that only works if the  the  a href=="School" but the I have different institutions not only school.

Comment: I have solved this using the next element twice after the div.  and it worked straight away without using the regex

Comment: Yes you are right.I have just mentioned extra regex based on your example.

Comment: No worries that always helps.